# How to print from pointers in radare2 in debug session

Tags: debugging, debuggers, radare2

when I am using the radare2 debugger, it happens that I have sometimes to examine variables and memory. Consider the following instruction

```
0x08048498      8b4508         mov eax, dword [ebp+arg2]
```

Assuming that I know that what in eax pointer to array of characters with null termination at the end (I mean string). So, `ebp+arg2` is pointer to that string.

when I type `ps @eax` I get what I expect, a string. But, I can get the same result by accessing `[ebp+arg_2]`. I tried many things including `ps` and `ps/` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the `afa` command (`a` for analysis, `f` for function, and the latest `a` for arguments), you should find the value of the args.

You can then use `pxr` (`p` as in `print`, `x` and in hexdump, `r` as in reference): `pxr 1 @ ebp+0x8`, `1` to get the first reference.

Comment: actually it is right except for it should be `pxr 4 @ ebp+0x8`  to get the first reference

Answer (score 2):

You should get the same result by `pf S @ ebp+arg2`.

```
pf[?][.nam] [fmt]              print formatted data (pf.name, pf.name $<expr>)
S       64bit pointer to string (8 bytes)
```

`pf S` stands for print formatted null terminated string referenced by a 64 bit pointer.

You might have to use arg2's actually value like 0x8.

I guess it is a renamed argument so you should look up in the function header what is it's value.