# How to print eax value with Radare2?

Tags: debugging, radare2, debuggers

I am solving a crack me challenge but I am stuck. The challenge executes several `jne` tests. The first test is the simpliest but I don't arrive to print the `eax` value to know the content of `cmp` instruction. According to this block of code :

```
|    ; DATA XREF from sym.main (0x804848e)
|    0x08048497      b88a55ea8b     mov eax, 0x8bea558a
|    0x0804849c      45             inc ebp
|    0x0804849d      f4             hlt
|    0x0804849e      83c004         add eax, 4
|    0x080484a1      8a00           mov al, byte [eax]
|    0x080484a3      38c2           cmp dl, al
|,=< 0x080484a5      753d           jne 0x80484e4
```

How can I print the `eax` value to understand what are compared in the instruction ?

`0x080484a1      8a00           mov al, byte [eax]`

According to [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11768/how-to-print-from-pointers-in-radare2-in-debug-session), I tried the `0x080484a1` but when I enter the command `pxr 1 @ eax+0x4`, nothing appears. If I enter the command `pxr @ eax+0x4`, this code appears :

```
0x080c288c  0x6f6c6165  ealo ascii
0x080c2890  0x00796768  hgy. ascii
```

The ascii printed is linked with the string compared `ksuiealohgy`.

Comment: does the execution reach that place ? there is a hlt instruction before i dont think your execution will reach this point if the flow was linear https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT_(x86_instruction)

Comment: Yes it reach that place.The problem is solved, thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you used `pxr` as you could get the output with `px 1 @ eax+0x4`. But another options would be that you could run this opcode and then read the register value of `al` to get that. But in order to do that you need to use debugger commands instead (of course you need to be in debugging mode):

```
[0x7f5953803e90]> dr?
Usage: dr   Registers commands
| dr                     Show 'gpr' registers
<snip>
```

So to get the value of `al` execute during debugging session:

```
[0x7f5953803e90]> dr al
0x00000090
```